# PostgreSQL Syntax for Sum with a Condition, using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have two postgresql tables: User and QualifyingEvents.  I am trying to get the sum of a column in QualifyingEvents for a particular user, specifically, the current_user (as defined by devise).

I am attempting to define "hours_total" in a ROR project.

This query works:

```
QualifyingEvent.sum(:hours_earned)
```

This query doesn't:

```
QualifyingEvent.sum(:hours_earned, :conditions => {"user_id = ?", id})
```

What's the appropriate way to "filter" for a particular user, specifically, the current_user that's logged in.

Here's my Rails schema.rb file (simplified):

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141220001323) do

# These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
enable_extension "plpgsql"

create_table "admins", force: true do |t|
 -- NOT RELEVANT, NOT SHOWING --
end

add_index "admins", ["email"], name: "index_admins_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
add_index "admins", ["unlock_token"], name: "index_admins_on_unlock_token", unique: true,   using: :btree

create_table "qualifying_events", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "course_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
  t.integer  "hours_earned"
  -- NOT RELEVANT, NOT SHOWING --
end

add_index "qualifying_events", ["user_id", "created_at"], name:   "index_qualifying_events_on_user_id_and_created_at", using: :btree
add_index "qualifying_events", ["user_id"], name: "index_qualifying_events_on_user_id", using: :btree

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"

  -- NOT RELEVANT, NOT SHOWING --
end

add_index "users", ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true, using: :btree
add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
add_index "users", ["unlock_token"], name: "index_users_on_unlock_token", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

Also, is there a good resource - other than ActiveRecord::Calculations http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.5/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html - for PostgreSQL and ROR syntax.  Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QualifyingEvent.where(user_id: current_user.id).sum(:hours_earned)
```

And if you've got the right associations set up, then the following would be better:

```
current_user.qualifying_events.sum(:hours_earned)
```